Redirect to Sign In Management using Google Play Game services v2
I'm implementing an App with Flutter and I'm using Google Play Game Services V2. With this version, Google removed the sign out functionality and the users must do it from the OS:
"The sign out method is removed, and we will no longer require an in-game button to sign in or sign out of Play Games Services." from https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/android/migrate-to-v2
According to Google (https://support.google.com/android/answer/12461859?hl=en), the process to manage sign-in preferences for games is the following:

On your device, go to Settings.
Tap Google.
Search for "Play Games."
Tap Change account for games.

Doing the steps above, you go to the screen below, where you can sign out or change the account. However, the user experience is pretty bad, as the user needs navigate through a lot of menus to reach this.
Google sign in management screen
Is there any way (action/intent/whatever) to go to this screen with a button/link? (and avoid making 7 clicks to go there via native OS).
Thank you in advance,
